# SSRS Report Text size displaying limitation

Tags: reporting-services

I want to display values of a column in SSRS report and that  particular column in some cases has values more than 100K characters while in my test only 32000 thousands characters can display in column in SSRS report.

When I retrieve report in SSRS it display following message because of too much text value in "Column1".

[image]

Below is the image of result set which display values of "Column1" in somecases more than 100K characters.

[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: I wonder what a report like this achieves.. regardless.. can you not split column one into more than one column and when the length of the first column exceeds or = max.. then move the rest to column 2 and so on and so forth? Does all the data need to be in one column?

Comment: Thanks Harry for approach, Actually requirement is like this. I know presentation of the report will look like a mess.

Comment: Is this for some sort of data extract?

Comment: if purely for presentation.. then you can do what I suggested.. remove the borders and padding between the columns and ensure the first character for column 2 on wards starts with a comma.

Comment: @Harry, it is actually a report for user's presentation which user will later save result into Excel . Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Of that's the case.. Why not create a view that the user can refresh in excel directly. Ssrs in not always he beat option.